# How can I use jasmine-headless-webkit with Django?

Tags: django, jasmine, jasmine-headless-webkit

I've checked out django-jasmine, and although it does most of what I need, it's missing a couple of features that jasmine-headless-webkit provides: automatic coffeescript compilation, and clean debugging backtraces. What is the simplest way to use jasmine-headless-webkit with Django?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [Karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma) instead (which is awesome).